# FPDF Cell with custom border

Tags: php, fpdf

I wanted to show data with custom position. the currency is align left and the number align right.

So i'm trying to make a cell that looks like 1 cell but it's made of 2 cell .

Here is part of my code

```
$pdf->Cell(5, 10, ' $ ', 'L', 0, 'L');
$pdf->Cell(45, 10, $r_purchases_t['purchase_total'], 'R', 0, 'R');
```

It's result is this :

```
|$         10,000.00|
```

Problem : It has no bottom border,how can i make custom cell border just left and bottom  side ?

If possible, i want some code like `$pdf->Cell(5, 10, ' $ ', 'L'||'B', 0, 'L');`

Answer (score 3):

**SOLVED**,
Apparently you can just combine border using `,` in border parameter.

So to add left and bottom border of the cell just using this code 
`$pdf->Cell(5, 10, ' $ ', 'L,B', 0, 'L');`

Answer (score 0):

```
$pdf->Cell(45, 10, ' $ '. $r_purchases_t['purchase_total'], 'L', 0, 'L');
```

Try This and adjust width of cell accordin to need.